# how to filter specific payload bytes in tcpdump?

Tags: tcp, tcpdump

I use command `tcpdump -x -r input.pcap` and have the following `tcp` packet:

```
18:05:08.139615 IP 192.168.5.117.12336 > 192.168.5.2.58542: Flags [P.], seq 4484:4604, ack 91, win 5792, options [nop,nop,TS val 3008071469 ecr 2239920620], length 120
    0x0000:  4500 00ac a172 4000 4006 0d12 c0a8 0575  E....r@.@......u
    0x0010:  c0a8 0502 3030 e4ae 1f09 8634 bb24 e0aa  ....00.....4.$..
    0x0020:  8018 16a0 1372 0000 0101 080a b34b 872d  .....r.......K.-
    0x0030:  8582 79ec d580 0008 7d08 0000 0000 0000  ..y.....}.......
    0x0040:  0000 fd0a ff6f 7308 1200 0a1c 0d0a 0901  .....os.........
    0x0050:  1112 0003 1e1f 0c10 010f 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0060:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0070:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0080:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x0090:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
    0x00a0:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

How can I filter byte `8582` at `0x0031`? and pipe it to some other command. Does `tcpdump` has any option to specify bytes to filter from the payload?

I need to filter `2 bytes` starting from `0x0030`.

Answer (score 0):

```
tcpdump -lx -r input.pcap | grep 0x0030 | awk '{print $2}'
```

I was looking to do something similar and settle on using grep to get the line for 0x0030, and then awk to split it by whitespace and print the 2nd field i.e. 8582.

The -l option to tcpdump ensures that output to stdout is immediate.